# Azure DevOps + Version Control Integration

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, commit

Using Azure DevOps as a way to track progress in development lifecycle but I don't want to manually have to move the tickets from "To Do" -> "In Progress" -> "Test" -> "Done". I would like this to happen when I work on some code and commit a change.

Currently the only thing I have found possible to do is move the ticket from "To Do" to "Done" by when carrying out a pull request I add "Fixes: TicketX". This is not ideal as it skips out the middle parts of the lifecycle when the work may not be complete at that moment in time.

Comment: I don't think any platform will give you that by default because it doesn't know when exactly did you pick an item from the backlog. You need to move it when you want to work on it.

Comment: hmm...It would be useful if this was possible though. For example if ticket number AB25 was in the backlog and I began working on it, it would be useful to add a comment in my commit for example "In Progress: #AB25" and this would move my ticket from backlog to In Progress.

Comment: yes, you could probably create a custom VSTS extension and let it handle the tickets based on incoming messages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/overview?view=azure-devops